# get the site domain name and split into two variables

Tags: javascript, url, dns

[image: website url case 1 & case 2]

I've a website url (please see the image above)
For case 1: I used the following code to get the domain name, so that the value of var "lastItem = com" and the value of var "firstItem = mysite"

```
var sName = location.host;

var item = sName.split('.');
var lastItem = item.pop();
var firstItem = item.join('.');
```

For case 2: This code doesn't work if the website url change. (if added prefix www). Please help.

Comment: You can do this with regular expressions, see here to learn more http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You can use my code, i asked following link for improvements:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571064/get-pure-domain-name-and-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sName = location.host;

var item = sName.split('.');
var lastItem = item[item.length-1]
var firstItem = item[item.length-2]
```

If your domain is something like mysite.co.uk it won't work. If you need to match any kind of URL to get the domain name you better using Regular Expressions.

Comment: So, the domain can be anything: mysite.co.uk, demo.mysite.co.uk, mysite.com, demo.mysite.com
Will the above code works?

Comment: How would it?  There's nothing magical about domain names to know which part is the host and which part is the domain.

Answer (score 2):

So, you basically always want the last two elements?

```
var lastTwo = sName.split('.').slice(-2),
lastItem = lastTwo[1],
firstItem = lastTwo[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sName = location.host;
var firstItem = sName.substr(0,sName.lastIndexOf('.'));
var lastItem = sName.substr(sName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
```